# Runtime error 13' Type missmatch VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

This is the code that tries to modify the background color of some cells depending on the condition. It worked in a friend's computer where i created the code but when I sent it to my computer and run it, the message type missmatch appeared.

Debuger stops at the assignation Cells(i,j).Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)

Maybe is it a compatibility stuff with excel version???

```
Sub Acumuladores()

Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Title As String
Dim numColumnas As Integer

numColumnas = 36

j = 1
Do While j < numColumnas
    Title = Cells(1, j)
    i = 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        i = i + 1
        If (i Mod 2 = 0) Then
            If (Title = "PV" Or Title = "PPALUNITCCY1" Or Title = "PPALUNITCCY1" Or Title = "IMPORTE_TOTAL_ACUMULADO" Or Title = "FXFORWARDPPAL" Or Title = "FXFORWARDRATE" Or Title = "FXFWDVTO") Then
               If Cells(i, j) = -Cells(i + 1, j) Then
                    Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            End If
            If (Title = "TIPOEMISION" Or Title = "STARTDATE" Or Title = "MATURITYDATE" Or Title = "DESCRIPTION" Or Title = "CECACUMTIPO" Or Title = "CECACUMRATIO" Or Title = "CECACUMRATIO1" Or Title = "CECACUMNOBS" Or Title = "CECACUMFREQ" Or Title = "CECACUMSTRIKE" Or Title = "CECACUMBARRERA") Then
                If Cells(i, j) = Cells(i + 1, j) Then
                    Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    j = j + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You have `-Cells(i + 1, j)`. That `-` is probably your issue.

Comment: `Cells(i,j).Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)` A shot in the dark. Put a breakpoint at that line. Find the value of `i` and `j` then physically check that cell and see if there is any formula error for example `#N/A`? For example if `i=1 and j=1` then manually check `cells(1,1)` which is `A1` and see if there is any formula error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the if statement:

```
If Cells(i, j) = -Cells(i + 1, j) Then
  Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Else
```

You have `-Cells` instead of `Cells`. So fix it using:

```
If Cells(i, j) = Cells(i + 1, j).Value * -1Then
  Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Else
```

Comment: But i need to compare the cell with the negative value of the next cell. How do i do this? And why that expression did not break in the computer i created the code?

Comment: try `Cells(i + 1, j).Value * -1`